# Hover on multiple div show a div

Tags: html, css

I want to make appear a div when I hover on an another div it work but not when I have multiple div. I don't unserstand why ?

[Here a simple code of what is happening](https://jsfiddle.net/4tnwes7g/10/)

**code:**

```
        <style>

        .hover_show:hover{
            display:block !important;
        }
         .show{
               width:100% !important;
               height: 20px !important;
        }
        .hover_show{
            display:none !important;
        }
        .show:hover + .hover_show{
            display: block !important;
        }
        </style>


        <div class='show'>div2</div>
         <div class='show'>div1</div>
        <div class='hover_show'>
                Content to show
        </div>
```

*On this snippet I would like to show the div content when I hover on div2.*

Comment: This is because `.show:hover + .hover_show` is only fired if `.hover_show` is immedialty after `.show:hover `. If you are sure that your html won't change in the future you can do `.show:hover + .show + .hover_show {}`

Comment: @AlexVand if this is answer you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`+` is the adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), but in your example `.hover_show` isn't adjacent to your `div2` element. You want [`~`: the general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

```css
.hover_show { display: none; }
.hover_show:hover { display: block; }

.show {
    width:100%;
    height: 20px;
}
.show:hover ~ .hover_show { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class='show'>div2</div>
<div class='show'>div1</div>
<div class='hover_show'>
    Content to show
</div>
```

[Read more about CSS combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators).

Comment: Down-voter, care to explain what's wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) (`~`) and rewrite your last selector in this way:

```
.show:hover ~ .hover_show {
   ...
}
```

in fact `.show:hover + .hover_show` works only when the two elements are adjacent (that is, when the `.show` element hovered is immediately followed by a `.hover_show` element).

This can't work if you have other elements between those two. In your example if you hover the first element the rule won't be applied because you have another `.show` element in the middle

The general sibling combinator looks instead for all **following** sibling, regardless if they are adjacent or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. hope so solve your issue

```
   .show:hover ~ .hover_show{
                    display: block !important;
                }
```